# get some HTML code with Selenium as BeautifulSoup does

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My question is simple:

Is it actually possible to get html code and print it out like BeautifulSoup does? For example, if I write:

```
body = webpage.find('body')
print(body.prettify())
```

I get the code. But if I write this:

```
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
print(body)
```

It returns,

> [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement
> (session="ee2650fd730fb28c03f80f1a66f3b4ff",
> element="fd532dfa-d134-45fe-b35c-7ef597437ac8")>]

so I don't know if there is some way to translate that into code or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the entire page source with:

```
print(driver.page_source)
```